# How to edit an observable?

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, firebase, observable

Before this, I was using Firebase as database service, so when I get the Observable from firebase and subsribe to it

```
const projectsFromDatabase = this.afDB.list(this.basePath, {
    query: query
});
console.log(projectsFromDatabse.subscribe(res => {console.log(res)}); // just for testing
return projectsFromDatabse;
```

I got something like this:

```
[
 {
   0:
     {data: 0, value : 0, $key: ABC}
 },
 {
   1: 
     {data:1, value:1 , $key: DEF}
 }
]
```

Now i'm moving from firebase to mongodb .So i have an observable get from an api:

```
const projectsFromDatabase = this
      .http
      .get(url)
      .map(res => {
        return res;
      });
    console.log(projectsFromDatabse.subscribe(res => {console.log(res)}); // just for testing
return projectsFromDatabse;
```

and get something quite different

```
[
 {
   0:
    {  
       ABC:{data: 0, value : 0},
       DEF:{data: 1, value : 1}
    }

 }
]
```

Is there anyway I can edit the second observable to become something like the first one, so that I can subscribe it later and get the same result 
I had tried to subscribe it, alter it , and push to a new observable but my observable length after that always 0, or maybe anyway else ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/decorator-svc-gt6ghl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdecorator.svc.ts)

What you need to do is to use `.map`, similar to what you do when you make `http` call.

In the below eg, I have added a new property to the response object which we receive from server. **Similarly, you can modify the response you are getting from your server before rendering it to the UI**. I tried to make my eg as live as possible so I used a live API. I hope you'll get the idea of implementation

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable,BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()

export class DecoratorService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
  getData(): Observable<any>{

  return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler')
     .pipe(map(d => this.modify(d)));
  }

  modify(data){
    data['myOwnProperty'] = "Hey There, I am added by decorator !!"
    return data;
  }

}
```

Comment: Using `map` operator to transform data is not enough?

Comment: Thanks men , yes I figure it out just by edditing the map function

Comment: @NgocTuanLam Cheers !